# delete blank rows on an excel worksheet, in a different excel workbook, using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have 2 work books. Book_A and Book_B.

I want to delete blank rows in Book_A worksheet1, from Book_B worksheet1.

I have written a code using VBA to delete blank rows.

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()

' this macro will remove all rows that contain no data

Dim i             As Long
Dim LastRow      As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1

  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
   ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

This code works and enables me to delete blank rows of a worksheet.

Say i have rows in Book_A, worksheet1,using the vba editor,

i insert a module for VBA project Book_A and type the coding,

and run the macro,

the blank rows in Book_A, worksheet1 get deleted.

............................................................................

**But:
This code will not enable me to delete blank rows in Book_A worksheet1, from Book_B worksheet1.

I want to delete blank rows in Book_A worksheet1, from Book_B worksheet1.

How can this be done? How do i edit my coding?
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do..

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()

' this macro will remove all rows that contain no data

Dim file_name as String
Dim sheet_name as String

   file_name = "c:\my_folder\my_wb_file.xlsx"  'Change to whatever file you want
   sheet_name = "Sheet1"   'Change to whatever sheet you want

Dim i             As Long
Dim LastRow      As Long

Dim wb As New Workbook

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file_name)

wb.Sheets(sheet_name).Activate




LastRow = wb.ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1

  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.ActiveSheet.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
   wb.ActiveSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need and should avoid `Select`/`Active*`

Comment: What is the alternative then? @chrisneilsen